# Could not run corda nodes inside docker container as corda-tools-network-builder.jar in corda not located

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am trying to follow Corda network builder I have installed Docker as well and trying to run the sample example where I have to run a jar file by running java -jar  -d . but not able to locate corda-tools-network-builder.jar jar file so I tried downloading external jar but is from https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/corda-tools-network-builder/4.1/ but it says its currupted can anyone help me with this I want to run corda nodes inside a docker containers

Answer (score 0):

Corda is now on the 4.4 release and 4.5 is coming out soon.

I don't know where the tutorial you found is from but you might have an easier time trying to run more recent demos that just run with a few gradle tasks.

In the case of the network builder take a look at the latest version of the docs for an updated tutorial :

https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/network-builder.html